# Is there a way to define steps within a TestCafe test?

Tags: testing, automation, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe

My project requires tests to be broken down into steps w/ associated pass/fail results. I found some old documentation where this is possible: https://testcafe.devexpress.com/Documentation/Getting_Started/Test_Code_Guide/

So something list this:

```
test('My Test', async t => {
  step('Step 1', async () => {
    // ...do something
  })

  step('Step 2', async () => {
    // ...do something
  })

  ...
})
```

Are test steps possible with the new version of TestCafe?

Answer (score 2):

The documentation you found is not related to the open-source TestCafe version.

The open-source TestCafe version does not allow performing the following test steps if an assertion/step fails. Refer to this thread to find more information:

[Continue test case on assert](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52206058/continue-test-case-on-assert)